# XML - XSL - FO XML Dot Leaders Mutliple Occurances

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, leader

I have hundreds of lines of text, being formatted in an XML doc that I need to output to a PDF and display as:

```
LEFT TEXT.......................................................................RIGHT TEXT
```

I discovered how to do this in the XSL, but it is currently running as a processing instruction, during FO output.
XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('leftrighttext')">
  <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
    <xsl:text>LEFT TEXT</xsl:text>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
    <xsl:text>RIGHT TEXT</xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
```

What the XML looks like (being used in a table):

```
<row>
<entry> <?leftrighttext?> </entry>
</row
```

Desired Output:

```
LEFT TEXT........................................................................RIGHT TEXT
NEXT TEXT WITHIN TABLE...........................................................OTHER TEXT
```

My question is how would I get the "LEFT TEXT" and "RIGHT TEXT" to be called from the XML document, instead of inputting the values directly in the stylesheet, such as:

```
<row>
<entry>LEFT TEXT <sometag> RIGHT TEXT</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>NEXT TEXT WITHIN TABLE <sometag> OTHER TEXT
```

Is there a tag I can create, or a string to identify the text before a tag, and the text after, input dot leaders between them?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Additional Information Requested:
I used the XSLT posted in the answer below, here is the XML doc I am trying to transform. I also followed the outline for the XML that wsas posted below. Please let me know what I'm missing...

XML:

```
<?xml-model href="http://docbook.org/xml/5.0/rng/docbook.rng" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://docbook.org/xml/5.0/rng/docbook.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="5.0">    
    <table>
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="235"/>
            <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="235"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry align="center">LSP</entry>
                    <entry align="center">RSP</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry align="center" namest="col1" nameend="col2">(PF) Takeoff Briefing<?leftrighttext?>PERFORM</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</section>
```

This is what I have for the beginning of the stylesheet:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs date"
extension-element-prefixes="date"
version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl-ns/current/fo/docbook.xsl"/>
```

Comment: Show a relevant sample of your XML, the XSLT you have so far and what kind of output you expect, exactly, for the XML sample.

Comment: I don't quite understand what XML you are looking at - the one that has the `<?leftrighttext?>` PI does not have any data, and what's the other one?

Comment: The <?leftrighttext?> is the PI I call in the XML, when I transform with the XSL to a PDF, the output produced is the text within the processing instruction template... so the PDF produced LEFT TEXT.................RIGHT TEXT.

Comment: But the XSLT process in general takes a single XML document and transforms it into a single output document. However, you show two input documents, that's a bit unclear.

Comment: The last XML document showing the row and entry with LEFT TEXT <sometag> RIGHT TEXT is what I hope I can accomplish. To use the text in the XML document, instead of in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 5):

I would stick with your original approach of using a processing instruction. You just need to use `xsl:apply-templates` to build up the `fo:table-cell`.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <row>
        <entry>LEFT TEXT <?leftrighttext?> RIGHT TEXT</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>NEXT TEXT WITHIN TABLE <?leftrighttext?> OTHER TEXT</entry>
    </row>    
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>                            
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('leftrighttext')">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block text-align-last="justify">LEFT TEXT<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>RIGHT TEXT</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block text-align-last="justify">NEXT TEXT WITHIN TABLE<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>OTHER TEXT</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Rendered PDF**

[image]

---

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

Looking at your update XML example I see that you have a default namespace (`xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"`). What you should do is declare that namespace with a prefix in your XSLT and then use that prefix in your XPaths.

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you could instead add `xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` and not change any of your XPaths.

It's hard to recommend something specific because you haven't shown a complete XSLT (or even a template that shows us the context of where the tbody is being created), so this is a complete guess.

Here's an example using your updated XML and declaring the `http://docbook.org/ns/docbook` namespace with the prefix `doc`.

(I didn't try to handle the table headers or anything like that just to keep it simple.)

**XML Input**

```
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="5.0">    
    <table>
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="235"/>
            <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="235"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry align="center">LSP</entry>
                    <entry align="center">RSP</entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry align="center" namest="col1" nameend="col2">(PF) Takeoff Briefing<?leftrighttext?>PERFORM</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
</section>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:doc="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:table">
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:tgroup/doc:tbody/doc:row"/>                            
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:row">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:entry"/>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:entry">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:entry/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('leftrighttext')">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:doc="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block text-align-last="justify">(PF) Takeoff Briefing<fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>PERFORM</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Rendered PDF**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to apply this XSLT, and I'm receiving an error when i try to transform it:                                                                                                      ERROR - Exception
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-body" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+)

Comment: @BSailor - Can you update your question with a sample xml and xslt that will reproduce this issue? That's the only way we can help you try to determine why `fo:table-body` missing required children.

Comment: @BSailor - You didn't add any additional XSLT to the question so this is a complete guess, but it looks like your problem is a default namespace. Please take a look at my edit and see if that helps.

Comment: I got it to transform; however, now the table separators  (colsep and rowsep) and header don't appear in the rendered PDF.